# Why is the linear momentum a moment map?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider a particle with mass $m$ moving in a constant speed $v$ along the real line $\mathbb{R}$, with coordinate $q$. Then its linear momentum is $p = mv$.

Now let's translate the physics into math, namely a Lie group action on a symplectic manifold. The phase space is the symplectic manifold $M := T^*\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, with coordinates $(q,p)$ and a canonical symplectic form $\omega := dq \wedge dp$. The Lie group $\mathbb{R}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translation along $q$ direction. This is a symplectic and Hamiltonian action. Note that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is still $\mathbb{R}$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_map), the moment map generalizes the linear and angular momentum. So a linear momentum can be viewed as a special case of a moment map.

My question is:
**In the above example, why is the linear momentum $mv$ a moment map $\mu: M \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathfrak{g}^* \cong \mathbb{R}$?**

Comment: That would be the equation of motion.

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica Care to explain more? What's $\mu$?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add a different question (since that invalidates existing answers). If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but please also do not edit to follow-up questions into your questions. Questions are supposed to contain nothing but information relevant to the question itself. Also, there [is no need to mark your edits with "Edit X"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/50583), the revision history is accessible to all users if they are interested in the history of a post.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for your efforts in this question. Do you have an answer to the [follow-up question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/519055/what-is-the-momentum-mapping-for-a-left-translation-group-action?noredirect=1&lq=1), by any chance? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 4):

I explain in general how the moment map leads to an actual map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to the algebra of classical observables $C^\infty(M)$ in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203655/50583), but I will exemplify the reverse direction for 1D translations in the following:

1. The translation algebra $\mathfrak{g}\cong \mathbb{R}$ acts on $M\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ as $f_c : (q,p)\mapsto (q + c, p)$ for some $c\in\mathfrak{g}$. The vector field that is the infinitesimal version of this action is of course $X_c = c\partial_q$.
2. The contraction of the symplectic form with this vector field is $\iota_{X_c}\omega = (\mathrm{d}q\wedge \mathrm{d}p)(c\partial_q) = c\mathrm{d}p$, i.e. $$\mathrm{d}(\langle \mu, c\rangle) = c\mathrm{d}p\tag{1}$$ by definition of the moment map.
3. The pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is just multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ and so the momentum map for translation is $\mu : M\to\mathfrak{g}^\ast\cong \mathbb{R}, (q,p)\mapsto p$ since then $\langle \mu,c\rangle(q,p) = cp$ and the defining equation $(1)$ is true. So the moment map of translation is "the momentum" in the sense that it maps $(q,p)$ to the momentum part $p$.

(If you run this logic in reverse, you start from $\mu$ and get the map $\mathfrak{g}\to C^\infty(m), c\mapsto c\partial_q$, i.e. the algebra homomorphism mapping abstract infinitesimal translations to their concrete generators, which is the viewpoint I took in my post linked at the beginning)

Comment: This looks reasonable although I haven't understood everything. But I'm confused after looking at an example from Page 74 in Audin's "Torus Actions on Symplectic Manifolds" (2nd Edition), which said: " If $H:W \to \mathbb{R}$ is any function and if the Hamiltonian vector field $X_H$ is complete, its flow defines a Hamiltonian $\mathbb{R}$-action, the momentum mapping of which is $H$. " Here $W$ is any symplectic manifold. We can take $W$ to be the manifold $M$ in our example. Then the moment map should be $H=p^2/2m$?

Comment: @YuhangChen Why should the moment map be $H = p^2$? Don't be confused by the terminology - the function $H$ in your quote is not the Hamiltonian, the "Hamiltonian vector field" just means that $X_H$ is defined by $\mathrm{d}H = \iota_{X_H}\omega$.

Comment: So the function $H$ should be just $H: (q,p) \mapsto p$ instead of the total energy?